# ASP MVC Amazon S3 File Exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I'm using the Amazon S3 Storage to cache dynamic resized images and serve them. Doing this I run into heavy Exception Issues.

**First of all I check if the needed image is already stored into S3:**

```
public bool FileExists(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            IAmazonS3 client;
            using (client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = _bucketName,
                    Key = fileName
                };

                using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
                {
                    // do something here and return TRUE
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception:{0}:{1}:{2}", this.GetType().Name, this.GetType().Namespace, exc.Message));
        }
    }
```

This is a nightmare. 3 Exceptions were raised if the file doesnt exists. I think thats not the way it should be done. BTW the performance is also lame.

So is there a better approach? May be parsing the REST answer or something else?

The REST would be like this:

```xml
<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>392DF1D491F5C39A</RequestId>
</Error>
```

**Raised Exceptions**

1. ```
   [AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist.]
   ```
2. ```
   [HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
   ```
3. ```
   [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
   ```

Comment: 1. [AmazonS3Exception: The specified key does not exist.]
2. [HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]
3.[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.]

Comment: Thanks can you edit your question and include that please?  It will help others help you

Comment: One exception is being raised.  The AmazonS3Exception is wrapped in the HttpErrorResponseException, which is in turn wrapped in the WebException.  All exception you receive from Amazon will be wrapped like this.

Comment: Yes but using Exception Handling to determine if a key exists is really a bad practice.